# how get a data of json in python

Tags: python, json, netbeans

I have this code , in this code i get a json object from a url(ajax)  and i need to get internal data, this is my code:

```
url = URL_BASE9


req = requests.get(url)
statusCode = req.status_code
if statusCode == 200:

html = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
#print(html)
```

and this is my result

```
`{'FiltroFechaInicio': '/Date(-62135586000000)/', 'Pagina': 1, 'ListHechos': 
 [{'contenido': '<div class="ExternalClass3DB02CFE22F84F3F998EBEA913E5A79B">
 <div><a 
 href="/Noticiascibe/hechos%20esenciales/NAVIERA/hes_2017060105740.pdf">
 hes_2017
 060105740.pdf</a></div></div>', 'Activo': None, 'FechaString': '15-06-
 2017', 
 'TipoAdjunto': None, 'UrlAdjunto': 
 '/Noticiascibe/hechos%20esenciales/NAVIERA/hes_2017060105740.pdf', 
 'Descripcion': None, 'UrlImagen': None, 'ClaseIconoAdjunto': 
 'iconoDescargaPDF', 'Fecha': '/Date(1497566727000)/'}`
```

how do get the content of data, thanks and have nice day

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same as with dictionary, you have a keys and values for every key

```
  my_dict = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2',
    'key3': 'value3'
    }
my_dict['key1']

# Out: 'value1'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a "JSON object", you're talking about a JSON **string**.

To convert a JSON string into an object you can use `json.loads(json_str)` from the json module ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.loads)).

example:

```
import json
json_str = '{ "FiltroFechaInicio": "/Date(-62135586000000)/" }'
my_obj = json.loads( json_str )
```

By the way, the JSON string you posted is both invalid and incomplete.
Valid JSON must have keys and strings enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: sorry, my english is not perfect, i need extract the data string of json because after extract the data i can insert the data in a database